# Change the background color of "Debit or Credit Card" Paypal button

Tags: button, paypal, payment

I am using PayPal smart buttons and would like to offer credit cards as a form of payment.

Since my website have dark mode, it reduces the visibility of the "Debit or Credit Card" button and make it seem disabled.

I am aware that there are multiple styles to choose from for the main PayPal button; however, I was wondering if the "Debit or Credit Card" button's background is also customizable.

Here is the current setup:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

White can be used.

```
paypal.Buttons({
            
            style: {
                color: 'white'
            },
```

Comment: code is incomplete and not described properly.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a code demo such as https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client , or a generator such as https://www.paypal.com/buttons/smart

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the accepted answer:

in addition to changing the theme to white, you can also add `mix-blend-mode:screen` to your parent div to increase readability on the "Powered by PayPal" text.

Noticed this messes up with the border radius for me so I've just changed the style.shape from 'rect' to 'pill'